# A hashtable of pointers in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to build an initialize a hashtable whose pointers point to another struct in my program.  But it seems to give me a segfault when I try to initialize(H). I think I may be allocating memory incorrectly, but I'm not sure if that's what a segmentation fault actually means.  The way it is set up, H->hashtable should be an array of hashnodes, right?  hashnodes themselves are the pointers to my other structs.  Why am I only getting a seg fault at initialize?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct Position{
        char data[12];
        struct Hashnode *previous;
        struct Position *next;
        char letter;
        char direction[5];
    } *position;

    typedef struct Hashnode{
       struct Position *INSIDE;
    } *hashnode;

    typedef struct hash_table{
       hashnode *hashtable
    } *HTABLE;


    HTABLE NewHashtable(){
     HTABLE H = (HTABLE) malloc(sizeof(struct hash_table));
     if(H == NULL){ printf("Malloc for new hashtable failed."); exit(1);}
     return H;
    }



    void initialize(HTABLE H){

        H->hashtable = (hashnode*) malloc(100003*sizeof(hashnode));

        int toofer;
        for(toofer = 0; toofer<100003; toofer++){
                 H->hashtable[toofer]->INSIDE = NULL;
                 }
            }

   int main(){
       HTABLE H = NewHashtable();
       initialize(H);

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: For one thing, you don't check if `H->hashtable` is `NULL`.

Comment: ugly: struct Position; *position; struct hash_table; *HTABLE. uppercase, lowercase, underscore, maybe camelCase.

Comment: @PeterMiehle, It looks like the microsoft naming convention: HANDLE, something->MEMBER etc. Why is microsoft still in business is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
HTABLE H = (HTABLE) malloc(sizeof(struct hash_table));
```

is just horrible. It mixes a `typedef`:ed pointer (why do people still do this?) with the underlying `struct` name, making it the reader's job to make sure they match. Plus, [that cast is a bad idea, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

It should be:

```
HTABLE H = malloc(sizeof *H);
```

if you insist on keeping the `typedef`.

That said, the code in `initialize()` is probably failing its `malloc()` call, which is not checked before being relied on. This is a very bad idea.

Further, there's confusion about *what* exactly is being allocated. The `malloc()` code allocates `100003*sizeof(hashnode)`, but `hashnode` is (again) `typedef`:ed as a *pointer*, not a `struct`. Then the pointers are dereferenced in the loop, causing mayhem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    H->hashtable = (hashnode*) malloc(100003*sizeof(hashnode));

    int toofer;
    for(toofer = 0; toofer<100003; toofer++){
             H->hashtable[toofer]->INSIDE = NULL;
             }
        }
```

The first line allocates a bunch of memory for `H->hashtable`. It contains random garbage.

Thus, when you enter the loop, `H->hashtable[0]` is random garbage (because all of `H->hashtable` is random garbage). But you attempt to follow that random garbage pointer in in your loop. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is the fastest way to get a segmentation fault.

Here's a way to help you see it. Say you decided to zero that memory to be safe. Your code would be:

```
    H->hashtable = (hashnode*) malloc(100003*sizeof(hashnode));
    memset(H->hashtable, 0, 100003 * sizeof(hashnode));

    int toofer;
    for(toofer = 0; toofer<100003; toofer++){
             H->hashtable[toofer]->INSIDE = NULL;
             }
        }
```

Clearly, after that `memset`, `*(H->hashtable)` is 0 since that sets all of `H->hashtable` to 0. So `H->hashtable[0]` is 0 too and thus `H->hashtable[toofer]->INSIDE` dereferences a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
H->hashtable = (hashnode*) malloc(100003*sizeof(hashnode));
```

should better be

```
...sizeof(struct Hashnode)...
```

Comment: In fact, it best be `H->hashtable = malloc(... * sizeof(*H->hashtable));`.

Comment: or even `H->hashtable = malloc(... * sizeof *H->hashtable);` in particular don't cast the return of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc